# C++:How to reading a binary file in a thread and writing it in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, binary

I want to reading a binary file in a thread and writing it in another thread.It works with small files ( like txt file) but not with large files ( like jpg file ). I try storage buffer in a vector, but it works like a queue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::mutex mtx;

vector<char *> q;
const int MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH = 100;
int string_size(char * str)
{
    int Size = 0;
    while (str[Size] != '\0') Size++;
    return Size;
}

void readFile()
{
  ifstream file;
  file.open("in.jpg", ios::binary);
  file.seekg(0, ios::end);
  int length = file.tellg();
  cout << length;
  file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  while (true) {
    mtx.lock();

    if (q.size() > MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH) {
      mtx.unlock();
      sleep(10);
      continue;

    }

    if (length - file.tellg() <= 1024) {
      int tmp = length - file.tellg();
      char *c = new char[tmp];
      file.read(c,tmp);
      q.push_back(c);
      mtx.unlock();
      break;
    } else {
      char *c = new char[1024];
      file.read(c,1024);
      q.push_back(c);
      mtx.unlock();
    } 

  }

  file.close();
}

void writeFile() {
  ofstream o;
  o.open("out.jpg", ios::binary);

  while (true) {
    mtx.lock();
    if(q.empty()) {
      mtx.unlock();
      sleep(5); 
      mtx.lock();
    }

    if(q.empty()) break;
    o.write(q.front(), string_size(q.front()));
    q.erase(q.begin());
    mtx.unlock();
  }

  o.close();
}
int main() {
  thread th_in(readFile);
  thread th_out(writeFile);
  th_in.join();
  th_out.join();
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `std::mutex::lock()` and `std::mutex::unlock()` manually, consider using [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: Explain your issue "it doesn't work". Crash? Wrong output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in `writeFile` function where `string_size` is called. Why do you assume that in JPG stream content null byte cannot appear? Suppose you read first block - 1024 bytes which has 0 value at 10-th position, the block is queued into `q`, then while writing you call `string_size` which returns 10 and the remainder of that block is not written into file - and will never be written because `erase` is called onto `q`.

You could store `pair` with pointer to data of block and its length:

```
vector< std::pair< char *, int> > q;
```

then in `readFile`:

```
if (length - file.tellg() <= 1024) {
  int tmp = length - file.tellg();
  char *c = new char[tmp];
  file.read(c,tmp);
  q.emplace_back(c,tmp); // <--- added
  mtx.unlock();
  break;
} else {
  char *c = new char[1024];
  file.read(c,1024);
  q.emplace_back(c,1024); // <--- added
  mtx.unlock();
}
```

and in `writeFile`:

```
if(q.empty()) { mtx.unlock(); break; } // in this place unlock should also be called
o.write(q.front().first, q.front().second); // <--added
q.erase(q.begin());
```

also instead of storing raw pointer in `q` consider using smart pointer like `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this piece of your code:

```
while (true) {
    mtx.lock();

    if (q.size() > MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH) {
      mtx.unlock();
      sleep(5);
      mtx.lock();
      continue;
    }
....
}
```

In case the `if` is true you lock the mutex **twice**, one before `continue` and then at the beginning of the `while` block.

The [mutex doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) say that this is Undefined Behaviour.